# How to create symlink in windows10 like creating symlink in linux

Tags: python, windows, symlink

I am trying to create a symlink in windows10 using this link https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/ but my problem is the symlink generated has a file extension of .link. With this, I cannot run my app using the linked file.

Comment: Use `os.symlink` in Python 3. You'll need SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege. By default it's only granted to elevated administrators, but you can grant this privilege to a group that includes standard users such as the "Authenticated Users" group.

Comment: But chances are slim that a typical Windows program will function properly when run from a symlink, not unless the link is beside the executable. Windows does not resolve a symlink to the final path in the process module list (e.g. `GetModuleFileName`), so the application directory will be wherever the symlink exists instead of its target. This is a problem. The application directory is fundamental in Windows. It's the first place searched by default in many cases, so many programs will not be able to find important DLLs and resources when run from a symlink in another directory.